Can my solution be improved (and is it correct...?)
UPDATE after seeing one of the comments below, I have gone back to the original paper and realised that the question is correct but my answer is the wrong way around. I have now updated my working/solution.
This question is from a university entrance exam from around 1910. I have slightly modernised the wording:
A certain quantity is first divided into $n$ equal parts and then into $n+1$ equal parts. If the product of the $n+1$ parts is $n$ times the product of the $n$ parts, find an expression for the quantity in terms of $n$.
Here is my solution (answers were not published back then, so I do not know if I am even correct!)
Let the quantity be $Q$.
The product of $n$ equal parts will then be $(\frac{Q}{n})^{n}$ and the product of the $n+1$ parts will be $(\frac{Q}{n+1})^{n+1}$
This means we need to solve $n\times (\frac{Q}{n})^{n}=(\frac{Q}{n+1})^{n+1}$ for $Q$
$\frac{n\times Q^n}{n^n}=\frac{Q^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$
$Q=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}$
Questions
1 - Is this correct or have I made an error somewhere? If so, where?
2 - Can this solution be simplified or improved?

3 seconds before a down-vote. That must be a personal record! I'm impressed you even read the entire question in that time. Is there something about my question you dislike? I am keen to learn.

Does it work for $n=2$? Why $(\frac{Q}{n})^{n}=n\times (\frac{Q}{n+1})^{n+1}$ and not $n\times(\frac{Q}{n})^{n}= (\frac{Q}{n+1})^{n+1}$?

"If the product of the $n+1$ parts is $n$ times the product of the $n$ parts" is expressed as $\left(\frac{Q}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = n \times \left(\frac{Q}{n}\right)^{n}$, you seem to have done it differently.

Excellent point. I'm going to dig out the original paper now and check which way around it was, because, as you rightly state, it makes a big difference.

It (now) looks fine to me.
